# Send String Over Bluetooth to Android Device on Arduino

Tags: android, python, string, bluetooth, arduino

I'm sending strings over Bluetooth to an Android device.

I have an Arduino board with a Synapse SNAP RF100 module and a RN42 Bluetooth module connected to serial ports.

The data is read from the RF100 module and written to the RN42 on Arduino using

```
Serial3.write(Serial2.read());
```

The code running on the SNAP is written in SNAPpy (a subset of Python) and is as follows:

```
photval = readADC(2)
myString = "Photocell Value: " + str(photoval)
print myString
```

The printed string is written to the RN42 which the Android device recieves and displays in a `TextView`.

The above code makes the Android device display `Photocell:`

As you can see `photoval` is missing.

The string is as expected on the Python side - so either the Bluetooth is altering it or the Android is.

Does anyone know what causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the Arduino code - I fixed it by reading incoming data with an iteration:

```
void loop() {
    char rxdata[14];
    if (Serial2.available() > 0){
          Serial2.readBytes(rxdata, 14);
          Serial3.write(rxdata);
   }
}
```

I can now see the full string I expected.